# Undefined reference to vtable in Qt Widgets [Codeblocks]

Tags: c++, qt, undefined, codeblocks, vtable

I'm getting the error "reference undefined to "vtable for FlussoAudio" in this code, i can't find a reason for this error.

**FlussoAudio.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include "FlussoAudio.h"

FlussoAudio::FlussoAudio(QWidget *parent)
     : QWidget(parent)
{
    //...Buttons and Layout...
    setWindowTitle(tr("Lettore Audio"));
    resize(500,400);
}
```

**FlussoAudio.h**

```
#ifndef FLUSSOAUDIO_H

#define FLUSSOAUDIO_H

#include <QWidget>

class FlussoAudio : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit FlussoAudio (QWidget *parent = 0);
};

#endif
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "FlussoAudio.h"
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    FlussoAudio Audio;
    Audio.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The Build messages are these:

```
/FlussoAudio.cpp|10|reference undefined to "vtable for FlussoAudio"|
/FlussoAudio.cpp|10|reference undefined to "vtable for FlussoAudio"|
/FlussoAudio.h|10|reference undefined to "FlussoAudio::staticMetaObject"|
/FlussoAudio.h|8|reference undefined to "vtable for FlussoAudio"|
/FlussoAudio.h|8|reference undefined to "vtable for FlussoAudio"|
```

I'm using codeblocks and g++ on Arch Linux.

Comment: How i can do this in codeblocks?

Comment: By telling codeblocks to use `qmake`, `cmake` or any other decent buildsystem that knows how to run moc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro Q_OBJECT is mean, if not used in a moc compilation. Erase the line or comment it // Q_OBJECT

Regarding moc: http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/moc.html

Comment: Thanks for help. Work! But What is a moc compilation?

Comment: moc = meta object compiler